# creating sequence using @SequenceGenerator

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sequence-generators

I would like to know if there is a way to define sequence generator java side. Generally we have sequence generators defined in database and we map them to entities using

@SequenceGenerator(name = "generator", sequenceName = "SEQ_FOO_ID"). But is there any way that hibernate itself generates the values instead of using sequence generators from database?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use a custom generator. The list is available in [the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5294). Some of them don't use the database: increment, and uuid*.

If you want a sequence number, the increment generator can be used, but it's very limited, because it's unusable if you have a cluster, or if any other process also inserts rows in the database.